# euclid's lemma for prime numbers

Tags: primes, proof, number-theory

Euclid's lemma says that if p divides ab, then p divides a or p divides b.
If this is the case then p is prime.

What about when p=4, a=8 and b=9.
p| ab   => p|72
then,
(p|8 or p|9) is true.
This infers that p is prime.
But 4 is not a prime number.
I am overlooking something, and I am not sure what it is. There is definitely no restriction on a,b, and p, other than they are all integers.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about number theory / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I am sorry, where did I mention that this is a software question? It might be because I am new to stackOverflow. Please close it then.

Answer (score 2):

The lemma is that if p is prime and divides ab then p div a or p div b.  Not that p must be prime if it divides a product

In your example p is relatively prime to b

Comment: My notes from class say, 
"An integer p is prime if and only if for all a,b in **Z** (the set of all integers), if p|ab then p|a or p|b."

Since this is an if and only if statement, if (if 4|72 then 4|8 or 4|9) statement is correct, then p must be prime, isn't it?

Comment: "In your example p is relatively prime to b"
@EoinS I appreciate your prompt input, but I don't understand what that has to do with the definition. 4|8 or 4|9. The "or" is inclusive. So if either of them are true then p is a prime number.

Comment: @tidbits The simple answer is that your class notes are wrong. "for all, b in Z, if p|ab then p|a or p|b" does not imply "p is prime". You even provided a counterexample.

Answer (score -1):

Forty minutes later I realized, this implies for all a and b in **Z**.
This means that for all possible a and b such that p| ab.

From my example, when p=4, we need to try 2 and 2, because 4 divides itself as well.